# Enzyme ShallowWrapper doesn't pass props into simple React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, enzyme

I'm writing a test for a simple React component that is passed in an object using props, and then loads text onto the screen from that object. Here's what I've got:

`QuoteBox.js`

```js
import React from 'react'

export default class QuoteBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (  
      <div
        className='quote-box'
        onLoad={this.props.initializeApp}
        >
        <p className='text'>{this.props.quote['text']}</p>
        <p className='author'>{this.props.quote['author']}</p>
        <button
          className='new-quote'
          onClick={this.props.newQuoteFromStore}
          >New Quote!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`QuoteBox.test.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

import QuoteBox from './QuoteBox'

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

describe('rendering', () => {
  it('loads correctly, if the right state is passed', () => {
    wrap = shallow(<QuoteBox />)
    wrap.setProps({
      quote: { author: 'Author One', text: 'Quote One' },
      newQuoteFromStore: () => {
        return { author: 'Author Two', text: 'Quote Two' };
      }
    })
    
    const quoteText = wrap.find('p.text')

    expect(quoteText.text()).toEqual('Quote One')
  })
})
```

When I try to run this simple test using `npm test`, I get this error message:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

      13 |         onLoad={this.props.initializeApp}
      14 |         >
    > 15 |         <p className='text'>{this.props.quote['text']}</p>
         |                              ^
      16 |         <p className='author'>{this.props.quote['author']}</p>
      17 |         <button
      18 |           className='new-quote'

      at QuoteBox.render (src/features/QuoteBox/QuoteBox.jsx:15:30)
      at ReactShallowRenderer._mountClassComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:883:37)
      at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:800:14)
      at renderElement (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:632:26)
      at fn (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:724:44)
      at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js:99:18)
      at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:724:18)
      at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:411:22)
      at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/src/shallow.js:10:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/QuoteBox/QuoteBox.test.js:18:12)
```

I made sure to set a value for the prop values I use in the test using `setProps`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shallow rendering the component without any props and then only after the component has rendered giving it props via `setProps`. You need to set the props when you shallow render so it has the info on the initial render. `setProps` is used "for when you are wanting to test how the component behaves over time with changing props."
Try:

```
let wrap;
const props = {
  quote: { 
    author: 'Author One', 
    text: 'Quote One' 
    },
    newQuoteFromStore: () => {
      return { 
        author: 'Author Two', 
        text: 'Quote Two' 
        };
      }
    }
 wrap = shallow(<QuoteBox {...props} />)
```

and then the rest of your test.